# Parse JSON object with gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to parse JSON like:

```
{"response":[123123, 1231231, 123124, 124124, 111111, 12314]}
```

With GSON, making

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
int[] friends = new Gson().fromJson(answer, int[].class);
System.out.print(friends[0]);
```

But get `Error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2`

How to parse this numbers in array?

Comment: Because you are parsing an object which has a `response` property, you don't parse the integer array. Get the property and you have your array.

Comment: @user1066946, How can i get JSON array from this answer.
JSONArray not provide constructor like JSONArray(JSONObject, "property") :(

Comment: @onCreate JSONArray and JSONObject are *not* part of Gson; they're the android built-in JSON parsing classes. See my answer for how to extract the array using the property name ("response") and Gson.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're going to want to create a model class first that GSON can bind your json to:

```
public class ResponseModel {

    private List<Integer> response = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public List<Integer> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResponseModel [response=" + response + "]";
    }
}
```

Then you can call

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ResponseModel responseModel = gson.fromJson("{\"response\":[123123, 1231231, 123124, 124124, 111111, 12314]}",
                                            ResponseModel.class);
List <Integer> responses = responseModel.getResponse();
// ... do something with the int list
```

Comment: The ResponseModel still does work? I have the same model but no luck java 1.8

Answer (score 7):

The other option you have outside of using a wrapper class is simply to get the array from the parse tree.

Use the `JsonParser` to create the tree, get your array from it, then convert to `int[]` using `Gson`:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
       String json = "{\"response\":[1,2,3,4,5]}";

       JsonObject jo = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
       JsonArray jsonArray = jo.getAsJsonArray("response");

       int[] myArray = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, int[].class);

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

    }
}
```

Note that you could also just work with the `JsonArray` directly and not convert it to an `int[]` depending on your use case.

```
System.out.println(jsonArray.get(0).getAsInt());
```

Comment: Erm, what is "tricky" about this? You'll note that at the bottom I also state that converting to an `int[]` using `Gson` may not be necessary. While I *personally* will generally model the JSON with classes , sometimes you just need the data, not a class hierarchy. It's also valuable to show the OP how things work :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
String json1 = "[{\"contactName\":\"3\",\"contactNumber\":\"3\"},{\"contactName\":\"4\",\"contactNumber\":\"4\"}]";

JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(json1);    
JsonArray array= json.getAsJsonArray();    
Iterator iterator = array.iterator();    
List<ContactDetail> details = new ArrayList<ContactDetail>();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    JsonElement json2 = (JsonElement)iterator.next();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ContactDetail contact = gson.fromJson(json2, ContactDetail.class);
    //can set some values in contact, if required 
    details.add(contact);
}
```

I got another form [here](http://blog.moleculea.com/2013/01/24/gson-simple-example/)

Answer (score 1):

A Kotlin soulution

```
val myResponse = Gson().fromJson(responseStr, MyResponse::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

Json value has an object as response which holds an integer array. You have to define its class correctly first:

```
class ResponseHolder {
    private Integer[] response;
}
```

or

```
class ResponseHolder {
    private int[] response;
}
```

or

```
class ResponseHolder {
    private String[] response;
}
```

Then use that class while parsing your json value to a java instance:

```
ResponseHolder responseHolder = gson.fromJson(answer, ResponseHolder.class);
```

Comment: *"note that int[] won't work for you."* ... erm, sure it will. Gson has no problem with primitive array types.

Comment: Thanks @BrianRoach I've edited my answer. Once I had a problem with primitive array types with Gson. Now I've checked that and it has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

`BEGIN_ARRAY` but was `BEGIN_OBJECT` means in the beginning it's Object not the array. If you will see in the Json, response property is the type of object and that object further contains the array. You can Parse it with different ways Using creating your own custom model class or without creating custom model class. If you don't wan't to create your Response Model class then simply parse it

```
final Type typeOf = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Integer>>>() {}.getType();
final Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new Gson().fromJson(Your_JSON_String, typeOf);

// finally get list of ints form map.
final List<Integer> listOfIntegers =map.get("response");
```

Answer (score -2):

Or use org.json included in Android:

`JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(answer);

    JSONArray jsonItems = jsonData.getJSONArray("response");`